# how can i know my application is in not working mode?

Tags: iphone

i have one application in that i want to know that is this in idle mode ?

how can i know this ?

in my application when it go in idle mode i want to stop one java script. or you can say when  no one using application for long time .

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Much better now. And you seem to have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`
this method is called when app goes to inactive state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIApplicationDelegate methods like applicationDidEnterBackground:,applicationWillEnterForeground: etc But may be you want to use NSNotification also to Achieve this.[Refer this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)